# Swap out 2x RS510 with GRX 1x?

Tags: crankset

I have a 2021 Cube Cross Race Pro, currently in a factory spec 2x set up. It’s the 105 hydro group set on it with a rs510 chainset in 50/34. I want to go 1x and looking at fitting a GRX chainset. Has anyone done this? I noticed the Q factor is only 1mm difference, but chainline is +5mm outboard which could lead to premature wear up the bigger end of the cassette. I’m not overly worried about this but just wanting to know if others had carried this out. TIA

Answer (score 3):

Crank manufacturers have gone this way with chainline on 1x supposedly as a way of preventing involuntary pickup in the small end of wide-range cassettes. It will work fine.

Note that all 135 or 142x12 bikes of a given speed count have virtually the same rear chainline in numerical terms. FC-RX810-1 isn't a Road Boost crank or anything; it's meant to go with any 135 or 142 road bike.